# How to get the text of the inside element of the next div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two divs... Then when I clicked the **1st div,** i want to get the text inside of **h3** of the **2nd div**
Here is my codes... But none of the jquery code is working.. any help to fix my code, please... thanks

**HTML**

```
<div class="timeline-badge" style="background-image:url(images/couple-9.jpg);">CLICK ME</div>
<div class="timeline-panel">
    qqqq
    <div class="timeline-heading">
        wwww
        <h3 class="timeline-title">Hello</h3>
        <span class="date"><i class="icon-calendar"></i>February 00, 2017</span>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-body">
        <p>III</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY / JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('.timeline-badge').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).closest(".timeline-panel + div + h3").text());
    alert($( '.timeline-badge > div:eq(0) + h3:eq(0)' ).children().text());
    alert($(this).nextAll( '.timeline-heading').eq(0).innerhtml);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rK4qc/119/

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply use ID's for this? Do you need to select them by class?

Comment: Will the "timeline-panel" `div` always be immediately after "timeline-badge" `div`?

Comment: my code abode (html) exists/occurs many times in my page... so I created one jquery to cater all the click function in all above html codes... i think it would be a little hassle if i use id in each h3 to get the text coz i have to type it one by one..

Comment: @john17 - okay, in that case, **Mohammad**'s answer should be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.timeline-panel` is next sibling of `.timeline-badge`. So you should use [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to selecting it. Then use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to finding `.timeline-title` in it.

```
$('.timeline-badge').on('click', function() {
  var text = $(this).next().find(".timeline-title").text();
  console.log(text);
});
```

```js
$('.timeline-badge').on('click', function() {
  var text = $(this).next().find(".timeline-title").text();
  console.log(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timeline-badge" style="background-image:url(images/couple-9.jpg);">CLICK ME</div>
<div class="timeline-panel">
    qqqq
    <div class="timeline-heading">
        wwww
        <h3 class="timeline-title">Hello</h3>
        <span class="date"><i class="icon-calendar"></i>February 00, 2017</span>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-body">
        <p>III</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i did not downvote... i just cant upvote your answer... this message occurs ..... Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery's siblings selectors https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

```
$('.timeline-badge').on('click', function() {
    console.log($(this).siblings());
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.. but i think there something lacking on your codes

Answer (score 0):

Go get it by the class name of h3

```
$('.timeline-badge').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).next().find('h3.timeline-title').text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of your h3 tag with:

```
$('div.timeline-panel div.timeline-heading h3.timeline-title').val();
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt response.. i place your code inside my jquery.. but no text is printed..

Answer (score 0):

use this code.

```
$(document).on("click",".timeline-badge",function() {
   alert("H3 IS " + $('h3.timeline-title').text());
});
```

and check this fiddle for the code.
http://jsfiddle.net/rK4qc/121/

For the second div just add div for it and get the text user the .text() function.

Comment: this is also working.. thanks  .. but can you explain , a simple and short explanation will do, the difference with your code, $('h3.timeline-title').text()   ..... with others code, $(this).next().find('h3.timeline-title').text()

Comment: in my code. I use the class you assign to h3 tag which is the `timeline-title`.  Using this class you can directly get the text because it will point to your h3 tag directly using the class. And that is one of the advantages of using the class to get directly the information you want to an element. In addition, you can also use ID, but for now, you need to understand classes for your current problem.

Answer (score 0):

this will work for you:-

```
$('.timeline-badge').on('click', function() {

alert($(this).next().find('h3.timeline-title').text());
});
```

Comment: thanks sir.. it's working.. didn't know that code is just simple as this.. :)